# Not able to install Netbeans IDE (PHP bundle) on OS X El Capitan

Tags: macos, development, java

I am trying to install Netbeans IDE (PHP bundle) on OS X El Capitan.

I am getting following error

> NetBeans IDE cannot be installed. This software can be installed with
>   Java 7 update 10 or newer. Please download and install the latest
>   update of Java 7 from
>   http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html and
>   restart NetBeans installation.

Following is error screenshot

[image]

PHP and some other bundles (HTML, C/C++) don't need separate java as they include JRE as mentioned on Netbeans downloads page - https://netbeans.org/downloads/

> HTML/JS, PHP and C/C++ NetBeans bundles include Java Runtime
>   Environment and do not require a separate Java installation.

am I missing out something here?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you have downloaded and are using the correct installer. Like your note says, it evidently should not require a separate Java installation.

Otherwise, just [install the JDK separately](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html).

Comment: I have downloaded and using correct installer. Still, problem persists.

Comment: Just install the JDK then try again.

Answer (score 1):

I did it for the C++ Bundle, but it should also work with other versions without Java support.

- After mounting the disk image, copy the Netbeans 8.1.pkg to a local folder.
- unpack it using Terminal with this command `pkgutil --expand NetBeans\ 8.1.pkg ./out/`
- open the `./out/Distribution` file with a text editor
- remove from the checkSystem function the part with the java check. Final result:

  `function checkSystem() {
      var mem_result = checkMemsize();
      return mem_result;
  }`
- save the file an package everything back with `pkgutil --flatten ./out/ Netbeans_fixed.pkg`
- now start the installation using the repackaged file

Answer (score 0):

The [page](https://netbeans.org/downloads/) you show for download does **NOT** include the JDK

> JDK 7 and later versions are required for installing and running the Java SE, Java EE and All NetBeans Bundles. You can download standalone JDK or download the latest JDK with NetBeans IDE Java SE bundle.

So try the combined download from [Oracle Java's page](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk-7-netbeans-download-432126.html) or I think better the JDK

Comment: Didn't get the point. For what do I need the JDK if I don't want to develop for Java? If the JRE is included it's enough to run it.

Comment: Oracle has made this not true - on OS X The Oracle JRE is just the stuff needed to run web apps - the old JRE does not exist i.e. /usr/bin/java is only affected by JDK